# How can I get address of a category member from a category tree?

Tags: java

I have an array of list of a category, shown as a json tree, for example:

```
{
  "id" : "level 1-1",
  "name": "animal",
  "child": [
    {
      "id" : "level 2-1",
      "name": "carnivores",
      "child" : []
    },
    {
      "id": "level 2-2",
      "name": "herbivores",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "level 3-1",
          "name": "deer",
          "child": []
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to get category has id "level 3-1" but still keep the tree, for example

```
{
  "id" : "level 1-1",
  "name": "animal",
  "child": [
    {
      "id": "level 2-2",
      "name": "herbivores",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "level 3-1",
          "name": "deer",
          "child": []
        }]
    }]
}
```

This is what I tried

```
private List<CategoryDTO> buildCategoryTreeById(String categoryId, List<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOS) {
        if (categoryDTOS.isEmpty()) return new ArrayList<>();
        List<CategoryDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CategoryDTO categoryDTO : categoryDTOS) {
            if (categoryDTO.getLevel() == 1) {
                if (categoryDTO.getId().equals(categoryId)) {
                    buildTree(categoryDTO, categoryDTOS);
                    list.add(categoryDTO);
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    private void buildTree(CategoryDTO parent, List<CategoryDTO> categories) {
        if (null == parent.getChild()) parent.setChild(new ArrayList<>());
        for (CategoryDTO categoryDTO : categories) {
            if (null != categoryDTO.getParentId() && categoryDTO.getParentId().equals(parent.getId())) {
                parent.getChild().add(categoryDTO);
                buildTree(categoryDTO, categories);
            }
        }
    }
```

My model

```
public class CategoryDTO implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String parentId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private int level;
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private List<CategoryDTO> child;

// Getters & setters

}
```

It shows only

```
"id": "level 3-1",
"name": "deer",
"child": []
```

My idea is to find its parent and add itself to parent's property `child` and use recursive to make it a tree, but the result is not as I wanted.

Please help me. Thank you.
Sorry if the tittle made you misunderstanding, I am not good at using words.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if (categoryDTO.getLevel() == 1)`? Doesn’t that mean you are only searching the top level?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think that's to find the root node.

Comment: So why doesn't it work? Have you stepped through it with the debugger. Maybe you aren't setting the parentIds?

Comment: Ah, pardon me, I removed it from my code before. The result is still the same as I mentioned above, please help me. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @tgdavies That line is from the code that get full category tree, I forgot to remove it. I did step through it, it has only 1 result

Comment: So when you step through your code, why are no child nodes added to the parent?

Comment: @tgdavies I think something's wrong in my logic. When I step through my code, I saw it has parents. My sample test has level 3, I saw it can get level 2 and level 1 parents, but I cannot find out why its output has only category level 3